# Constructing a rule for finding the remainder when $3^n$ is divided by 13 for any given $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am working on a problem set for a group-theory course and I am trying to construct a rule for finding the remainder when $3^n$ is divided by 13 for any given $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

I notice that: $3^0 \equiv 1 \ (mod \ 13)$, $3^1 \equiv 3 \ (mod \ 13)$, $3^2 \equiv 9 \ (mod \ 13)$, $3^3 \equiv 1 \ (mod \ 13)$, $3^4 \equiv 3 \ (mod \ 13)$, and $3^5 \equiv 9 \ (mod \ 13)$. So there appears to be a cycle which repeats 1,3, and 9 depending on whether the $n$ in $3^n$ is congruent to either of 0,1, or 2 (modulo 3).

More precisely, it appears that:

$\bullet$ $3^k \equiv 1 \ (mod \ 13)$ when $k \equiv 0 \ (mod \ 3)$.

$\bullet$ $3^k \equiv 3 \ (mod \ 13)$ when $k \equiv 1 \ (mod \ 3)$.

$\bullet$ $3^k \equiv 9 \ (mod \ 13)$ when $k \equiv 2 \ (mod \ 3)$.

However, I am unsure how to prove that this holds. Any help would be appreciated here.

Comment: Considered induction?

Comment: I have however I am unsure how to do it. I have already looked at the related post here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1432927/determining-a-rule-for-the-remainder-when-3n-is-divided-by-13

however, I do not understand Thomas Andrews' answer.

Comment: @letsmakemuffinstogether I think it would have been more appropriate to ask for more explanation in a comment to Thomas Andrews' answer rather than to re-ask the question. That way you'd be getting an explanation straight from the source, and also you'd avoid posting a duplicate of an existing question which will surely be marked as such and closed.

Comment: What do you know about $ab$ mod $n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you've checked that $3$ has order $3$ modulo $13$, i.e. $3$ is the smallest positive integer $k$ such that $3^k\equiv 1\mod k$. Hence for any $k$, write $k=3q+k\bmod 13$. We have 
$$3^k=3^{3q+k\bmod13}=\bigl(3^3\bigr)^q\cdot3^{k\bmod13}\equiv 1^q\cdot3^{k\bmod13}=3^{k\bmod13}.$$

Comment: If I understand what you're saying, I have shown that 3 has order 3 modulo 13 and so all I need to do is do what you've done and establish that $3^k = 3^{k \ mod 13}$ which would provide a rule for calculating the remainder when $3^n$ is divided by 13?

Comment: You're absolutely right! Of cours this is valid for any modulus, in particular when you apply Little Fermat.